# cloth sim with implicit integration unstable problem

Tags: integration, simulation, physics, implicit

Im implementing a gpu based cloth simulation using mass-spring model with a backward euler integration.
The linear system is solved by using the conjugate gradient solver with filter. Everything is done in GPU. 
I think as an implicit integration it should be stable like many paper pointed out, but it is unstable just like 
the emplicit method. Most of time, when the time step size reaches a certain value (depending on the stiffness), the CG refuses to converge and goes into a infinite loop.

Although I've checked the code over and over again and read many papers, I still couldn't find out the reason.
The cloth moves correctly and the animation is much more convincible than the one using explicit integration, so i guess 
the forces are computed correctly. Is there anything I missed to cause the instability?

I've been tackled by this strange problem for days......
Any one can help? any suggestion i would really appreciate

thanks alot in advance!

Comment: How many elements does the cloth have? Have you tried the case a one-dimensional thread moving in a two-dimensional space? What's the simplest model that gives this behavior?

Comment: What order of magnitude is the step size?  About 1 millisecond, about 1 second, or even bigger?

Comment: When you day implementing a gpu based simulation, what tools are you using? OpenCL? Or something else? I'm interested in this sort of thing also.

Comment: There is no silver bullet - even backward euler has regions of instability.  The best you can hope for is to programatically detect diverging results and special case them, or limit the number of iterations and hope it gets into a stable state again later.  I've had a lot of luck on CPUs using verlet integration for stiff systems - there was a good article on it on Gamasutra in an article about Hitman once.

Comment: I am not in cloth simulation field  but my spring mass models are usually stabilized by adding friction of movement in air (liquid/gas)... F = velocity^2 * c1 or velocity^3 *c2